# Closing Pygame Window

Tags: python, pygame

I just spent a fair amount of time finding a 64-bit installation of pygame to use with python 3.3, ([here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame%20/)) and now am trying to make a window. However, although the window opens up fine it does not close when it hit the x button. In fact, I have to close IDLE to close the window. I am running a 64 bit version of Win 7. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

When I append

```
time.sleep(5)
pygame.quit()
```

It still doesn't close. My only guess would be that pygame.quit might go inside one of the loops, but even if that were resolved I would greatly prefer being able to close the window when I want to.

Comment: Try running the code from command prompt and see if the problem persist

Comment: Have you looked at [the relevant question on the pygame FAQ](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#In%20IDLE%20why%20does%20the%20Pygame%20window%20not%20close%20correctly?)?

Comment: what pygame version are you using?

Comment: @Alfgaar To be honest, I don't remember. It was a while ago :)

Answer (score 38):

Most pygame tutorials seem to suggest exiting by calling `pygame.quit()` and then `sys.exit()`. I have personally run into problems (was on a unix system though) where this still did not close the window properly. The solution was to add `pygame.display.quit()` specifically before `pygame.quit()`. That should not be necessary as far as I can tell, and I'm afraid I don't know why that solved the issue but it did.

Comment: pygame.init() initializes all pygame modules (display, mixer, font, etc.) and pygame.quit() does the contrary, closes all modules. one can initalize a module per turn, if you want to use only display you do pygame.display.init(), no real need to call pygame.init... but, according to what you said, pygame.quit is faillling on closing the display module....

Comment: Thank the lord, finally an answer that works! Been looking everywhere for an answer that wasn't just restating the pygame docs method. Personally this got rid of the window that was otherwise frozen, but the process still hung on pygame.quit(). I initialized only the display using @Alfgaar's method, and then removed pygame.quit() altogether to finally close it all the way.

Comment: I had this problem trying to use pygame 1.9.6 from the Spyder 4.1.3 IDE, but my tutorial only had `if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()`. Once I added `pygame.quit()` on a line before `sys.exit()`, it worked great.

Comment: @Joe that's curious—I have the exact same problem as you did (using the same Spyder version, and same pygame version), but adding  `pygame.quit()` doesn't quite do the trick for me...

Comment: @singularity, this is what worked for me
    ```for event in pygame.event.get():```
        ```if event.type == pygame.QUIT:```
            ```pygame.quit()```
            ```sys.exit()```  in four lines of code, which I cannot figure out how to do in a comment.

Comment: This also works when using keydown event (event.key == pygame.K_) to exit the pygame screen. Using IDLE on my Mac, sys.exit() alone causes spinning beachball. But adding pygame.display.quit() specifically before sys.exit() fixes it. Thanks, Erikun!

Answer (score 22):

One way to close the window is to call sys.exit():

```
import sys
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

I put sys.exit() after pygame.quit(), because pygame.quit() quits the pygame software and sys.exit() closes the window.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure but try this Because you code runs fine on my system after I add `pygame.quit()` at the end

```
import pygame
import time
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")
running = True
try:
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    pygame.quit()
except SystemExit:
    pygame.quit()
```

Its perhaps because as Idle is made on Tkinter and thus Tkinter and Pygame main loop do not have a mutual understanding.
Your code will run very well on command prompt though.

Comment: The except SystemExit works, but it still closes IDLE. Also, when I open command prompt it returns the error "pygame.error:video system not initialized." Any idea how to solve this? And by the way, thanks for the help.

Comment: Well I cant figure out why is it closing the IDLE (not in my case).
Also mind that it may be the problem that you are replacing your code `pygame.QUIT` with `pygame.quit()`.
`pygame.quit()` is a function that closes pygame (python still running) While `pygame.QUIT` just checks if pygame is running or not.

Comment: I put `pygame.quit()` function after the while loop to make sure that pygame is not running after the while loop.
do not use it while checking ( `if-else` statements).

Answer (score 4):

This was the final code that worked for me on OSX whilst keeping the kernel alive on Jupyter.  EDIT -   it does still crash the kernel sometimes  :-(

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Also needed to downgrade ipython to get rid of some magic alias warning messages using:

```
conda install ipython=7.2.0
```

apparently that issue is due to be fixed in ipython 7.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Suffered the same issues on Python 3.7.4 while running it from in IDE (Spyder 3.3.6). In my case the pygame.quit() would not completely close the program. 
Nonetheless, adding quit() or exit() did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the top:

```
import sys
```

Add this where you need to quit:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the following command:

`sys.exit(0)`

notice: You will need to import the sys library in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE interferes with how pygame runs the code. Try to run it from the commandline or the terminal. The problem should disappear.

Answer (score -2):

To answer the original question: You must call `pygame.quit()` after breaking the main loop. One elegant solution goes as follows:

```
def run():
    pygame.init()
    while True:
        # ...
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Handle other events
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return pygame.quit()
```