# Pygame not quitting properly

Tags: python, pygame, exit

Lately my game did not stop when I called my routine to exit.

In various tests I could narrow the error down to when `pygame.quit()` is called. At this moment the program freezes.
I wrote a short program to verify that it was not anything funky in my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.quit()
```

This resulted in the same error.

I use `python 2.7.6` and `pygame 1.9.1release` on `Ubuntustudio 14.04.4 LTS`and *not* Idle

Edit1:

No Error is risen. With error I mean that the program does not stop as expected rather then just idles around. My guess is that some async process is still running in pygame.

Comment: Share your relevant code and error.

Comment: What do you want to happen after "quit", something other than freeze/halt?

Comment: @PirateX No error is risen and relevant code is already in question.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud The program should terminate. Normally python returns control to user when the script is finished.

Comment: Seems to be a dupe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882415/closing-pygame-window), which suggests adding `sys.exit`. Actually, the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) indicate that you don't need to call `quit`, and can just let the script terminate normally.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The problem is that `sys.exit()` invokes `pygame.quit()` and therefore results in same situation. I chose to name `pygame.quit()` because it makes it more obvious where the error might be.

Comment: What if you call neither, and just let execution hit the end of the script?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, that works. However it is very unpractical and just makes the code less obvious. Also this moves the process of exiting from the exit function to the "end" of the program. In addition it may solve the problem but it still does not clear the source of error which might be a bug in Pygame or less likely in Python itself.

Comment: I do not have this problem in my `pygame 1.9.1release`. I would try initializing and quiting specific parts instead and seeing which module causes the hang.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in idle? If so, idle generally requires the shell window to close before the pygame window will close. Try running the program directly through terminal if you haven't already.

Comment: Although the limitations on commenting while not having enough reputation are understandable, if you know you have an answer to this question, please, edit and elaborate it respecting the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing good answers.