# pygame window won't close

Tags: python, pygame, window

I'm currently following Eric Matthes's Python Crash Course (1st ed.), and am trying to make a pygame program. However, I've been having trouble closing the pygame window, and trying all the mentioned solutions in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882415/closing-pygame-window) haven't worked for me, unfortunately. (I'm working with Python 3.7.6, Spider 4.1.4, and pygame 1.9.6.)

My current code looks like this:
(I initially followed the book but then modified it many times alone the way)

```
import sys

import pygame

def run_game():
    
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))

    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    running = True
    
    while running:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        
run_game()
```

Might there be anything I'm missing or doing wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Update:

Python always goes into "not responding" mode when I use pygame:
[image]

Comment: Please explain further what you mean by "having trouble closing the pygame window".  Your exact code works OK for me, and by that I mean: I click the window titlebar-control (x) and the window closes, program exits.

Comment: Whenever I run the program and the window pops up, and when I try to close it, I get a neverending spinning pinwheel and when I check my applications, it says Python is "not responding". However, when I run my other programs (that don't use pygame), python works fine.

Comment: Might it be a problem with my application or computer..?

Answer (score -1):

That might help you:

```py
import pygame
import time
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World")
running = True
try:
   while running:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               running = False
   pygame.quit()
except SystemExit:
   pygame.quit()
```

I got this solution from here: [Closing Pygame Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882415/closing-pygame-window)

Comment: Thank you for the input, but as before, I'm locked into the spinning pinwheel that won't go away. At this point, I'm wondering if it's my computer that's causing the error (I've been getting messages that my storage is running low, if that helps at all)...?