# Pygame Window not Responding but no Error

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started learning pygame but I've had an error which shows pygame not responding after some time. It would really help if someone could find my bug! Here's my code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

def player():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))
 
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
             
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
     
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Why do you thing the problem is related to the code? This is likely a problem with your system.

Comment: So how do I fix my system I don't have a clue.

Comment: We do not know your system.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited knowledge of pygame, it is likely that you set `running = True` and did a `while True:` statement, causing too much memory to be used and the script to crash after some time.

You need a proper termination that uses `pygame.quit()`, followed by `sys.exit()`. Setting `running = False` does not terminate the script.

Try this code:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323453/4420129)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `pygame.quit()` at the end of your code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

def player():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (200, 150, 100, 50))
 
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
             
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
     
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```