# Pygame screen dosen't close

Tags: python, macos, pygame, anaconda, sublimetext3

I'm a Macbook user and I have just recently started learning programming games using python.
my issue is that every time I try to close the screen it doesn't close.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
width = 800
hight = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width , hight))
game_over= False
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
               sys.exit()
```

When I point the cursor to the screen it turns to a circle... [Cursur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6b7D.jpg), so usually I just press **force to quit** "on the snake icone" in the dock
So how can I fix this and make the screen close just by pressing the close button ?
I'm using python 3.
Thank you.

Comment: You say

    while not game_over:
        ....
But the thing is you said `game_over = True` so the loop will never run. Set `game_over = False`

Comment: You are right, but I'm still having the second problem.

Comment: You don't have a FPS limiting clock. Put `clock = pygame.time.Clock()`, where you declare your variables. And do `clock.tick(60)` (Put this in the main loop at the end. 60 is the FPS / Frames Per Second). This allows you to limit your game's speed.

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything. But I have found the solution : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882415/closing-pygame-window) . However, I still don't understand why the first code didn't work for me and worked for the guy in the tutorial.

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882415/closing-pygame-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full edited and tested code :

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
width = 800
hight = 600
running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width , hight))

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
```

Test on Linux mint with visual studio code. Tested more than 5 times. Expected results.